# How to embed thumbnails from flickr that link to bigger colorbox images with drupal and ckeditor

Tags: drupal-7, colorbox, flickr, ckeditor4.x

After 1 day searching and testing I'm wondering if it's possible to embed or insert a photo from flickr (or from google+ it's the same problem) in a node using drupal 7, ckeditor 4.5.6 and colorbox (for example).

More precisions:
What I want to achieve is to embed thumbnails from flickr that I can resize and move (like shown [here](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/captionedimage.html)) and are compatible with colorbox (or anything similar).
I've been testing all day with the ckeditor plugins image2, autoembed and embed, it's quite impressive the potential of it, but every flickr link pasted in the editor turns into a gallery (??) that is not resizable, and I don't need the whole gallery.

An good example of what I'd want [here](http://lolandese.altervista.org/) but this is done with a flickr filter of the drupal flickr module, it does the job but without the awesomeness of the ckeditor widget system, meaning : I have to copy every link, my user id, change the css, for each photo...

Has anybody done that ?